# personalize rich message using jsf2 and richfaces4

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, validation

Im working on a web application using `JSF2` and `RichFaces4`. Im using rich:messages for one of my forms and I want to personalize the message. the default show me the id of the form and of the component. I used the attriute validatorMasseage but it's dosent work this is my code:

```
> <h:inputText label="Name" styleClass="value" 
>                       id="name" style="width:220px"
>                       value="#{individualBean.longname}" 
> validatorMessage="My message ">
>                        <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="8" /> 
>                       <rich:validator/>
>                   </h:inputText> <rich:message for="name" />
```

By the way I used the attribute label of the `inputText` to show it in the message. If I want to do the same thing to a `rich:select` i can't find the label attribute?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

What is the message that you see? You do have two validators there, one is client which will be invoked on change and one server-side (f:validiteLength). Make sure you know which one is invoked when.

Comment: I want to display 'My message' when the focus is lost from the inputText and the string entred is < or > of min & max